# GenerateKeyEvent and GenerateTouchEvent are not generating events if a sleep or delay is added after it in the code

Tags: events, tizen

I am launching an app and then trying to generate a key event say "HOME". If I call a sleep function after generating the event. The APIs don't generate the events. Without sleep it works properly.

```
pAc = AppManager::FindAppControlN(appId,operationId);
AppLog(GetErrorMessage(GetLastResult()));
if(pAc)
{
    AppLog("Launching Applicaiton");
    result r = pAc->Start(&URI,&MIME,null,null);
    AppLog(GetErrorMessage(r));
    delete pAc;
}

AppLog("Home Key Generated");
SystemUtil::GenerateKeyEvent(KEY_EVENT_TYPE_PRESSED,KEY_HOME);
AppLog(GetErrorMessage(GetLastResult()));
SystemUtil::GenerateKeyEvent(KEY_EVENT_TYPE_RELEASED,KEY_HOME);
AppLog(GetErrorMessage(GetLastResult()));

sleep(2);
```

All AppLogs display `E_SUCCESS`, but still events are not generated. Can somebody help as to what is wrong here?